# Different solutions while integrating stiff equation

Tags: c, differential-equations

I am trying to integrate Rosenzweig-MacArthur model (equations) using Backward Differentiation Method using CVODE in C for stiff equations. I have to specify tolerance value for integration. Depending on the tolerance value I give, I get different solutions. I am not able to see which one is the correct solution. Can you please tell me what should (criteria for choosing) the tolerance value be?

Comment: I have no idea, but if somebody else does they probably won't help without a little code sample!

Comment: There is not one Rosenzweig-MacArthur model but several, which one is it? Which one of the several CVODE methods do you use? Did you read the accompanied paper (http://robotics.stanford.edu/~scohen/cvode.paper.pdf)? Some of the related papers (e.g.: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.4434 , https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.070/abschlussarbeiten/masterthesis_pfh.pdf). Did you use a different solver (e.g.: one out of e.g.: the list in https://globaljournals.org/GJSFR_Volume13/2-Numerical-Approach-for-Solving-Stiff.pdf)?